# Adding OR in Joi schema for time check

Tags: javascript, joi

I have next check

```
endTime: Joi.date().iso().min(Joi.ref('startTime'))
```

What I need to add something like: endTime:

```
Joi.date().iso().min(Joi.ref('startTime')) or Joi.date().iso().equal(Joi.ref('startTime'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Joi.alternatives](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#alternatives) to test multiple validations:

```
Joi.object({
  startTime: Joi.date().iso(),
  endTime: Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.date().iso().min(Joi.ref('startTime')),
    Joi.date().iso().equal(Joi.ref('startTime')),
  )
})
```

Anyway, I don't think you need to use `.equal`.

By using the `.min` you are saying that your `endTime` must be larger than or equal to `startTime`.